# How to close input or output stream when using Kotlin File's extensions

Tags: java, kotlin, file, stream, kotlin-extension

Do we need to close input or output stream when we use Kotlin's File.readText or File.writeText extensions

```
file.readText()
file.writeText("something")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readText` and `writeText` methods call the `use` method on the Input and OutputStream.
(See: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/FileReadWrite.kt#L108)

According to the documentation this method automatically closes the object afterwards.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html

So there is no need to close it manually.